# Duplicate Flag Error: The flag is defined twice : First in package and Second in module inside package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, flags

The stacktrace is pretty clear about the cause of the error. But I am unable to figure about the root cause. I have a package abc and there is a module inside the package called abc.py. In abc.py, I have defined Flags . When I run the code, I get an error saying `DuplicateFlag Error: The flag 'config' is defined twice: First from abc, Second from abc/abc.py.`

I havenot imported the module abc.py in other files. Can a python expert tell me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what is causing the issue. But the fix for it is to delete all the attribute in the flags before you actually define the flags using the following code:

```
for name in list(flags.FLAGS):
      delattr(flags.FLAGS,name)
```

I hope this helps. Anybody who know the actual cause of the issue is welcome to answer it for precisely.

UPDATE: The cause is partly answered in this [Running a module in a package, importing a subpackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830856/running-a-module-in-a-package-importing-a-subpackage) . The takeaway is : If you're running the module as a script a lot, you probably should make a new top-level script module that import the module from the package and runs the desired code . This prevents the module full of code from potentially existing twice, and also lets you benefit from cached bytecode being loaded from a .pyc file (which may make your program a bit faster to start up).

My package had cyclic dependency. Hence that could be the issue. I didnot even need to delete the attribute after i move my main script out of the package and run it normally.